# Yet another Grid question

Tags: modeling

K. I'm stumped. I'm building game pieces like walls and doors, etc. I have Units set to Millimeters > Metric > Unit Scale = 0.1000. My game pieces are measured in increments of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, etc units.

What settings do I use for Grid display so that (as I understand it) grid lines are very 1m and sub-division lines are every 16m. No matter what I change the grid is still seems to be 10x10. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust these, you just need to go to the overlays tab,[image]

and adjust the scale, and the subdivisions to your liking.

I hope this is helpful, happy blending!

Comment: Is that 2.8x? I forgot to mention I'm using 2.79b. Is it tucked away somewhere?  Everywhere I look I can't find it, and the manual has no visual reference on viewport overlays.